# How do I handle exceptions when incorrect enum is given from @ReuqestBody in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, enums

I want to receive enum in @RequestBody. When correct value of enum is inputted to @RequestBody, it works perfectly fine. However, When an incorrect value is given it gives me error status 400.

I want to handle exceptions for when a incorrect value of enum is given. I've researched a bit and some people says that I can handle these exceptions by implementing it like this.

```java
@Component
public class EventTypeConverter implements Converter<String, EventType> {
    @Override
    public EventType convert(String s) {
        return EventType.valueOf(s.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

However, it did not change anything.

I know that I can do something like this, by receiving a String and converting it afterwards and handle exception from here. But I want to know if I handle enum conversion exceptions by using @ExceptionHanlder which would become very simple and clean(I think) or any other clean and simple way to do this.

```java
public enum EvenType {
    // enums...

    @Getter
    Character type;

    EvenType(Character type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public static EvenType of(String eventType) {
        return EvenType.valueOf(eventType);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example does not provide exact information how you would like to handle exceptions but in general if you think it is more clean you can use ExceptionHandler like this (simplified example using int). Say you have a method like:

```
@GetMapping("checkNumber/{longValue}")
public ResponseEntity<Integer> checkNumber(@PathVariable int longValue) {
  return ResponseEntity.ok(longValue);
}
```

Now if your provided value is not possible to instantiate as an Integer handle it like:

```
@ExceptionHandler(NumberFormatException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Integer> handleNumberFormatException(final NumberFormatException nfe) {
  // Do what ever needs to be done and maybe call the controller method again.
  return checkNumber(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

Not saying this is the best option nor that you should use this. It depends mostly on what you actually want to achieve when exception occurs.

Comment: Is there a class for exceptionHandler that handles Enums? Like, which class could I use to handle exceptions for incorrect enum value?

Comment: As name states ExceptionHandler handles, well, exception. The class that is thrown when enum fails is IllegalArgumentException. That is thrown also in many other cases. So then you might want to implement your handler so that it checks the request and determines what to do, is it enum or what. Might not be so clean.

Comment: Also the message in exception could be parsed, but...